# Amazon Elastic Inference very low usage still high cost

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow

I'm interested in running inference for a personal project, meaning that it'll only be used when I'm demonstrating the app (once or twice per day realistically).

I'm running a faster R-CNN model that takes up about 2GB of memory.

Is there any way to use Elastic Inference in such a way that I'm only paying for those few seconds that I'm using inference daily?

I'm guessing the answer is no - my reasoning is that I'm paying to have my model in memory, waiting to run inference. But I was curious if (hoping that) there's something important that I'm missing so that I might use elastic inference without it costing me a fortune to run a little side project.

Comment: How heavy of a load is it? Could you potentially perform the inference on your personal computer or on a low cost cpu node?

Comment: @cmxu with a 1.2 GHz processor it takes ~ 10s to perform inference on one frame, and unfortunately I'm looking to get the performance as close to realtime as possible

Comment: I don't know if Amazon does it, but if I remember Google Cloud advertises 'per-second' pricing. I don't know exactly how their policy works, but you could look into it, but yeah you'll always have to wait to get things loaded into memory if you want to go this route. I don't think any service will let you just sit on gpu memory space without charging you.

Comment: @cmxu yeah, that's what I was afraid of. Now I'm looking into the possibility of loading into memory when the app is opened, and then dropping from memory when closed. Might be a trick to get around the high costs...